# T-SQL Trigger - prevent duplicate, but not always

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to avoid INSERTS and UPDATES which could duplicate field's value, **but not always.**

I have a varchar field **Cat_Catalog**.  in table **Catalog**.

I can have two rows with **Cat_Catalog**'s value "123" duplicated, but I cannot have duplicated field **Cat_Catalog** which starts with 'KAT' word (so I cannot have 2 rows with "KAT123" Cat_Catalog's value)

The following trigger i made doesn't work fine because field that's going to be updated starts with KAT trigger always raise error (variable @IfExist always return true - it is probably because of AFTER UPDATE,INSERT syntax).

I would like to avoid using INSTEAD OF syntax because updates are generated by some API which to i have no documentation and I'm not sure what to do in case when value doesn't starts with 'KAT'.

```
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Catalog_InsertUpdateCatalog]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--If first three characters are 'KAT' 
--then check for duplicate and raiseerror

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Catalog_InsertUpdateCatalog] ON [dbo].[Catalog]
FOR UPDATE,INSERT
AS
set nocount on;

DECLARE @CatalogInsert varchar(50)
DECLARE @IfKat varchar(10) = 'FALSE'
DECLARE @IfExist varchar(10) = 'FALSE'

SELECT @CatalogInsert = Cat_Catalog
FROM inserted

--Does It starts with 'KAT' ?
IF (@CatalogInsert like 'KAT%')
BEGIN
    SET @IfKat = 'TRUE'
END

--Check for Duplicate
IF EXISTS(
            Select * from Test.dbo.Catalog t
            where t.Cat_Catalog = @CatalogInsert
        )
        BEGIN
            SET @IfExist = 'TRUE'
        END

IF ( @IfExist = 'TRUE' and @IfKat = 'TRUE' )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Catalog allready exists: %s , ISKAT:%s , EXIST:%s', 16, 1, @CatalogInsert, @IfKat, @IfExist);
    END
```

`

The problem is that I don't know how can I check the current value to be updated  allready exists in **Catalog** table (check must be done before update).

Comment: your trigger code is not safe if more than one row is inserted or updated.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw since you assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @CatalogInsert = Cat_Catalog FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: For now I would like to simplify that in our system there is no API which do multiple row INSERT. How can I achieve this for single row update/insert? How should i modify my code?

Comment: Wouldn't a CHECK CONSTRAINT solve this?

Comment: I was sure that CONSTRAINT works for all entered values not only for those which starts with 'KAT'. Am I wrong? If both solutions would work - which is more productive, trigger or constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this ***new version***:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Catalog_InsertUpdateCatalog] ON [dbo].[Catalog]
    FOR UPDATE,INSERT 
    AS BEGIN
      set nocount on;
      --Check for Duplicate
      IF EXISTS(
         Select 1 
         From (
            -- Updated
            SELECT 
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Cat_Catalog) Cnt, 
              Cat_Catalog  
            FROM dbo.Catalog 
            WHERE 
               Cat_Catalog LIKE 'KAT%'
         ) t
         Join inserted i ON t.Cat_Catalog = i.Cat_Catalog AND Cnt > 1
      )
      BEGIN
         RAISERROR ('Catalog allready exists!', 16, 1);
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      END

    END
```

This trigger check the existence of rows with the same [Cat_Catalog] field as in the inserted (or updated) rows. If duplicated rows exists and [Cat_Catalog] starts with 'KAT' trigger RAISE error + rollback transaction.

**UPDATED:** I change trigger. It should now work correctly (i test it). Trigger FOR UPDATE, INSERT fires **after** changes take place in table. So we need check duplicate rows in the table. 
I do it throught COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Cat_Catalog) but you may check it in a more familiar way:

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) Cnt, 
        Cat_Catalog  
    FROM 
        dbo._Catalog 
    WHERE 
        Cat_Catalog LIKE 'KAT%'
    GROUP BY
        Cat_Catalog
```

Comment: It doesn't work - i'm trying to do update with any KAT number and It always raise an error "catalog allready exists'. i tried  to do an update with Cat_Catalog = KAT12312112312 and It says it allready exists - when its not

Answer (score 1):

Using [CHECK constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) instead of a trigger would be a better solution, since triggers are executed much later in the transaction and eventual rollback could be expensive. You can define check constraint as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsDuplicate(@col varchar(50))
RETURNS BIT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX('KAT', @col) = 1 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Catalog] WHERE [Cat_Catalog] = @col) > 1
        return 1;

    return 0;
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE [Catalog]
    ADD CONSTRAINT chkForDuplicates CHECK (dbo.IsDuplicate([Cat_Catalog]) = 0)
GO
```

Have in mind that if you already have duplicate "KATxxx" values in the table you'll have to either delete them or create the constraint with NOCHECK clause.

Comment: I appreciate the last information - that would cost me some time haha

Comment: CHECK constraint is the better approach in my opinion, because otherwise you'll prolong the transaction and will have costly rollbacks. If you think this is a good answer, please consider upvoting.

Comment: While trying to ALTER TABLE - Cannot find the object "dbo.Catalog" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. Table name is correct - and im logged as sa user. I'll check it tmrow

Answer (score 0):

Use Instead OF Trigger instead After Trigger.

If your problem with Instead OF Triggers, then you need to use NOT Eqals operator to avoid such wrong indication to passed. I supposed to say

```
      DECLARE @CATALOG_PK BIGINT;
      SELECT @CATALOG_PK = CATALOG_PK FROM INSERTED

  --Check for Duplicate
   IF EXISTS(
        Select * from Test.dbo.Catalog t
        where t.Cat_Catalog = @CatalogInsert
        AND CATALOG_PK <>@CATELOG_PK LIKE t.CATALOG LIKE 'KAT%' 
          )
    BEGIN
        SET @IfExist = 'TRUE'
    END
```

However this will fail in-case of multiple UPDATES or INSERTS done.

Comment: If I try to do update Cat_Catalog with '123' value, nothing is being updated

Comment: Add like operator in select statement LIKE t.CATALOG LIKE 'KAT%'

Comment: Tell me, this solution force me to write code in case if Cat_Catalog is not a  duplicate, right?

Comment: But I don't really know what API is going to update, I can miss something this way. What if there will be new field created in table - this trigger have to be updated too.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MyCatalog_InsertCatalog] ON [dbo].[MyCatalog]
FOR INSERT
AS

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT I.* 
    FROM Inserted I 
    INNER JOIN MyCatalog M 
        ON M.Cat_Catalog = I.Cat_Catalog 
    WHERE I.Cat_Catalog  LIKE 'KAT%' )
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Insert Catalog already exists:  ', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END

GO

CREATE TRIGGER [MyCatalog_UpdateCatalog] ON [dbo].[MyCatalog]
FOR UPDATE
AS

IF  EXISTS(
    SELECT I.* 
    FROM Inserted I 
    INNER JOIN MyCatalog M 
        ON M.Cat_Catalog = I.Cat_Catalog 
    INNER JOIN deleted d 
        ON d.Cat_Id = i.Cat_Id 
    WHERE I.Cat_Catalog LIKE 'KAT%' AND d.Cat_Catalog <> i.Cat_Catalog)
BEGIN

    RAISERROR ('Update Catalog already exists: ', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

**EDIT**

You could combine both triggers into one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MyCatalog_InsertUpdateCatalog] ON [dbo].[MyCatalog]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

IF  EXISTS(
    SELECT I.* 
    FROM Inserted I 
    INNER JOIN MyCatalog M 
        ON M.Cat_Catalog = I.Cat_Catalog 
    INNER JOIN deleted d 
        ON d.Cat_Id = i.Cat_Id 
    WHERE I.Cat_Catalog LIKE 'KAT%' AND d.Cat_Catalog <> i.Cat_Catalog)
BEGIN

    RAISERROR ('Update Catalog already exists: ', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
ELSE BEGIN
   IF EXISTS(
       SELECT I.* 
       FROM Inserted I 
       INNER JOIN MyCatalog M 
           ON M.Cat_Catalog = I.Cat_Catalog 
       WHERE I.Cat_Catalog  LIKE 'KAT%' )
   BEGIN
       RAISERROR ('Insert Catalog already exists:  ', 16, 1);
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
   END
END
```

Comment: I will check them in 1 hour - thank you for your time. I'll edit this comment after check.